# Wheel Came Off 3.5T Horse Box While Driving - Most Likely Cause?

Tags: wheels, safety, mot

About 4 months ago I had my Horsebox MOT’d and had brand new tyres on every wheel.

Last week while driving down the dual carriageway/highway, we heard a loud bang, I tried to brake but had no brakes, I took my foot off the accelerator and used my handbrake slowly to pull us into a lay-by just ahead, as we came to a stop one of my rear wheels rolled past us across the carriageway.

I have spoken to the garage who did the work and they are refusing to fix it and have accused me of lying about what happened.

What I need to know, how could this have happened and is it likely the garage did not tighten the wheel nuts properly? All 6 nuts were gone and the guy who recovered the vehicle said he thinks it’s the garage who is ultimately responsible, can anyone advise me on this please?

Comment: What other damage was there? If none, what is the line of least resistance? Attributing blame and getting compensation, or just fixing it? *Who is ultimately responsible* might be a question for SE Law, but the bottom line is *you* are responsible. Did you do the daily check of the tyres and wheels before setting out with a vulnerable cargo? Also many tyre shops recommend that you check the torque settings soon after. Did you?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Hard to say, but the fact that it's been *four months* of driving on it indicates it is *not* the garage's work that caused the issue. Maybe there was a blowout, but that should not result in a wheel coming off the car. If the garage used something faulty, then it's the manufacturer, not the garage at fault. It could be that kind of thing, but without a technical investigation, it's impossible to tell.